# I can't integrate Hibernate Validator into a javaweb project using the spring framework

Tags: java, web

I tried to add hibernate validation to my web project, but if there is a jar package in the project: spring-context-indexer-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar, it will cause the program to be thrown when the program is running: java.lang. annotation.AnnotationFormatError: Duplicate annotation for class This exception. This will prevent me from integrating hibernate validation into my web project. How can I solve this problem?

```
 package CarTest;

import java.util.Set;
import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation;
import javax.validation.Validation;
import javax.validation.Validator;
import javax.validation.ValidatorFactory;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
       class Car {
    @NotNull
    private String manufacturer;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 2, max = 14)
    private String licensePlate;

    @Min(2)
    private int seatCount;

    public Car(String manufacturer, String licencePlate, int seatCount) {
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
        this.licensePlate = licencePlate;
        this.seatCount = seatCount;
    }
    //getters and setters ...
}

public class CarTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
        Car car = new Car(null, "DD-AB-123", 4 );
    Set<ConstraintViolation<Car>> constraintViolations =     validator.validate(car);         
        System.out.println(constraintViolations.size());
        System.out.println("must not be null:-----"+constraintViolations.iterator().next().getMessage()); 
    }

}
```

If you add the spring-context-indexer-5.0.6.RELEASE jar to the library, the following exception will occur.

```
INFO: HV000001: Hibernate Validator 6.0.16.Final
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.annotation.AnnotationFormatError: Duplicate annotation for class: interface javax.validation.constraints.NotNull: @javax.validation.constraints.NotNull(message={javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}, groups=[], payload=[])
    at sun.reflect.annotation.TypeAnnotationParser.mapTypeAnnotations(TypeAnnotationParser.java:360)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotatedTypeFactory$AnnotatedTypeBaseImpl.<init>(AnnotatedTypeFactory.java:139)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotatedTypeFactory.buildAnnotatedType(AnnotatedTypeFactory.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.TypeAnnotationParser.buildAnnotatedType(TypeAnnotationParser.java:79)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.getAnnotatedType(Field.java:1170)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.AnnotationMetaDataProvider.findCascadingMetaData(AnnotationMetaDataProvider.java:618)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.AnnotationMetaDataProvider.findPropertyMetaData(AnnotationMetaDataProvider.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.AnnotationMetaDataProvider.getFieldMetaData(AnnotationMetaDataProvider.java:225)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.AnnotationMetaDataProvider.retrieveBeanConfiguration(AnnotationMetaDataProvider.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.AnnotationMetaDataProvider.getBeanConfiguration(AnnotationMetaDataProvider.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.BeanMetaDataManager.getBeanConfigurationForHierarchy(BeanMetaDataManager.java:232)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.BeanMetaDataManager.createBeanMetaData(BeanMetaDataManager.java:199)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.BeanMetaDataManager.getBeanMetaData(BeanMetaDataManager.java:166)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:157)
    at CarTest.CarTest.main(CarTest.java:47)
```

This is the jar package I introduced.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2Lt4.jpg)

This is just a small case. Because hibernate validation is added to my web project, these jar packages are inevitably put together.But I don't know how to solve this abnormality, I hope everyone can help.

Comment: Sorry, this is the first time I have posted a question here. I am not very familiar with it. Thank you for your reminder. I have re-edited it.

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace as (code formatted) text, not as an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Eclipse or anything using the JDT compiler from Eclipse?

Because I had a very similar issue with it when working on Hibernate Validator (I'm the project lead of HV).

It doesn't happen with all the tests of the code base but for some, it just ends up with this error.

When compiling with javac (using Maven for instance), the tests pass correctly (and I can even run things from Eclipse as long as it's not the JDT compiling the classes).

Comment: The development tool I use is the NetBeans IDE. I am trying to import a newer version of spring, there will still be this exception

Comment: So NetBeans does not use JDT but do you have the issue if you compile everything outside of the IDE? I don't know if you use Maven but do the equivalent of a `mvn clean install`.

Comment: I didn't use Maven, just manually import the jars I depend on. I tried to compile the CarTest case program with javac. Even if the sptring jar package is put into the classpach folder, it can be compiled and run normally. Only when compiling with the IDE will the problem occur.

Comment: Yes so basically NetBeans compiler has the same issue as the JDT. Not sure what to do about it, apart from raising a bug for the NetBeans team (and in the meantime use another IDE - not sure if Eclipse still has this issue, otherwise IDEA).